# Reading certain paragraphs out of text file in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to parse certain paragraphs out of a text file.  The paragraph I am trying to parse is labeled as so:

ABST

PAL    An abrasion-resistant laminate is prepared by providing an ultra thin
      coating of mineral particles and micro crystalline cellulose on the
      surface of conventional printed paper, followed by impregnating the paper
      with a conventional laminating resin, and then using the print paper so
      obtained in a laminating process without the necessity of using an overlay
      sheet.

PARN

So far all I have gotten is:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
   for line in f:
        if line.startswith("ABST"):
            print f.next()
```

This is only leaving me with the first line of the paragraph. What I would like to is something along the lines of:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
   for line in f:
        if line.startswith("ABST"):
            *print lines until next header*
```

I realize this is not too complicated but I have been stuck in a rut so any suggestion will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as f:
   flag = False
   for line in f:
        if line.startswith("PARN"):
            flag = False
        if flag:
            print line
        if line.startswith("ABST"):
            flag = True
```

Should do the trick... Straight and to the point. In any case, you can let the loop handle the iteration for you, just make sure you remember if you should print or not.

Comment: Thank you this did help alot, but I should have been more clear, the next header is not always 'PARN', which still leaves me with some issues.

Comment: @hoosiers123, is there a finite set of headers?

Comment: No there are multiple text files with differing numbers of headers and differing headers.

Comment: @hoosiers123, you need to clarify what *is* a header, before you try to recognise them.